# checkbox validation and floating image

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, css

A button lies in a different form. When a user clicks on a button, a new field would be visible. Can I use CSS to do this?

Plus, how can I jump from `form1` to `form 2`?

Here is my code:

```
   <form id="form1" action="#"> 
      <input type="button" onclick="form2">  
   </form>   
   <form id="form2">   
       <input type="checkbox">    
       <input type="button">  
   </form>
```

Also, how can I be put an image in a website and retain its position even when the window is being scrolled?

Comment: You want to show the second form after the first button is clicked?

Comment: what you want to achieve ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the image, use `position: fixed;`

And

```
(function($) {
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#form1').click(function() {
            $(this).hide();
        });
    });
})(jQuery);
```

But i really don't understand why you woulld want to do that...

Comment: for the first one i want that when i click on the button it will disapear and i would see form2 at that place

Answer (score 0):

You could use jquery and css to achieve this. Firstly, you would need to hide the second button, and then add an event to the first button to show the second button when you click the first.

Something like:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#form2").hide();

    $("#1 input").click(function() {
        $("#form2").show();
        $("#1").hide();

    });
});
```

This would initially hide the second form, and then setup a click event on the first button to show the second form. Is this what you had in mind?

As for the second part of your question, you can use the `position: fixed` css property to set any element fixed on the page. You also need to position the image, eg:

```
<img id="myimage" src="img.png" />
<style>
#myimage {
  position: fixed;
  left: 10px;
  top: 10px;
}
</style>
```

This would set an image fixed at 10px from the left and top of the screen, no matter if you scroll or not.

Answer (score 0):

i didn't really understood your question, jumping is a hard goal to achieve with coding (ALERT sarcasm here).
anyway i think you'll need some jquery:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){

        $('#form2').hide();
            $('#form1').show();

        $('#button').click(function(){
            $('#form2').show();
            $('#form1').hide();
    });
```

and the html should look like this:

```
<form id="form1" action="#"> 
      <input type="button" id="button">  
   </form>   
   <form id="form2">   
       <input type="checkbox">    
       <input type="button">  
   </form>
```

but i'm still confused about what you're trying to do

Comment: this is what i wanted bro...
but how can i do the jquery part with java script

Comment: well you might want to use jquery instead of pure javascript. it shorten your code and has a smarter sintax. you just need to include this `<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>` in the `<head>` section of your html. if it helped you please consider accepting my answer by clicking the checkmark on the left :). cheers

Comment: http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-qMCwU70KRak/UWimVuNQa7I/AAAAAAAAAiU/k1C638lfTWA/s1600/Capture.JPG

the output is kind of like this image even after <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

Comment: this is because you're trying in local. try with putting the HTTP protocol like this `<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>`